# tcpdf footer -> Long length text in footer not coming to new line

Tags: customization, footer, tcpdf

I am generating pdf for my client application using `TCPDF` by `customising footer`. My Client wants to show data in `footer` which are dynamic along with the page number. The problem I am facing is when the data becomes longer than the pdf width the data doesnt move to the next line and some texts are getting cropped.

`Can somebody suggest me solution by which I can shift some text to new line? similar to the one be do in HTML by adding <br>.`

Or

`Is there a way by which the text moves to next line automatically when the length of the text in footer exceeds the pdf width?`

Answer (score 1):

Extend the class as per example 3 or use the following code

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        $foot = 'Line 1 \n Line 2 \n 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages()';

        $this->MultiCell(0, 10, $foot, 0, 'C');
    }
}

// create new PDF document
  $pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I tried everything with TCPDF but it didn't work. 
Later I used MPDF which is a really wonderful PDF generation library and it works perfectly well now.